# Lithium ion solar battery charger circuit using SPV1040

Tags: solar-cell, lithium-ion

I'm studying to build a solar battery charger and I came across this attachment link

[STEVAL-ISV012V1: lithium-ion solar battery charger](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/application_note/a7/c2/04/60/f9/96/42/77/DM00048561.pdf/files/DM00048561.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.DM00048561.pdf)

It's what I was looking for except that I want to use 5V/0.8W 160ma solar panel instead of 0.4W used in the circuit.

So, want to know If I can use this part [Amazon UK - 5V/0.8W PV](https://www.amazon.co.uk/160mA-Solar-Panel-Module-Charger/dp/B00KG0HSTA) in the place of 0.4W. And also as per the document the circuit components has to change with PV cell range, could you please guide me how to determine.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No.  This regulator is Boost only PV to LiPo and 5V is greater than 4.2V

> "The PV panel can be replaced by a different one as long as Voc  < VBATT_max and Isc< 1.65 A. "

Comment: Hi Tony, thanks for the answer. I also found this circuit, is this something I can try 0.8W?. http://www.st.com/content/st_com/en/products/evaluation-tools/solution-evaluation-tools/energy-and-smartgrid-solution-eval-boards/steval-isv006v2.html